# Adding an Outlet downstream from a switched outlet

Tags: wiring

I'm getting a gas insert installed into a formerly wood burning fireplace. The workmen intend to install an outlet to plug in a blower fan. The closest source of power is an exterior outlet in the driveway on the other side of the wall. That outlet is controlled by a switch inside, in another room. I know if they just tap off that outlet, the switch will control both the old and the new. I want the new fireplace outlet to be hot (no pun intended) all the time. I'm sure step one is to replace the 2 wire + ground from the switch to the existing outlet with a 3 wire + ground. Beyond that I could use some help. The power source hits the switch first.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have attic access finding a line up there that is an always hot to a light fixture may be an easier route than tapping the hot side of the switch but just guessing here. Most lighting circuits have the ampacity to add a blower. A bathroom only branch circuit would would be one of the few places not code compliant to tap.

Comment: is this all wired in conduit?

Comment: It will be about the same amount of effort, to run a 2-wire from the switch box directly to the new outlet, as to replace the 2 wire from the switch to the old outlet with a 3 wire plus run a two-wire between the outlets. - The new 2-wire need not pass through the old outlet box, even if it ends up passing adjacent to it.

Comment: Jason - it will be.
Ed - no attic access :(
A. I. - I'm kind of married to the scenario I described. The fireplace wall is all stone. The back in the driveway is brick and will have to be drilled.

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the boxes in question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following your scenario, modify the wiring like this:

[image: Adding an unswitched outlet]

This requires adding one conductor to the run between the switch and the existing outlet. If your wiring is in conduit then this should present no serious problem.

Comment: Sorry for the slow response, took a long weekend and just returned. Thanks A. I. for the diagram.

Comment: Also thanks to everyone for all the help.

Comment: When you took the [tour], @TomH, you may recall that the proper way to say "thanks" 'round here is to click the up arrow next to all answers that help you (if there are more than one) and click the check mark next to the one that helped the most.